# Can use <> or != inside statement only

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, if-statement, plsql

I have a procedure to loop through records from one table with a cursor then initate a insert statement into another table.

I am receiving this error in the If Statement `!= ALL`

```
 Begin

 If V_Item = V_Item_G 
    And V_New_Part Is Null   
    And (V_Delete_G Is Null or V_Delete_G != 'Y')
    And Status_G != ALL  ('KNOWN', 'NEW', 'UNKNOWN', 'SOLD') 
 THEN INSERT INTO PART     
    VALUES ( V_Item, V_New_Part);

  End IF;

  End;
```

Note that `NOT IN` does not work.

Using `not in` does not insert any values. When I manually troubleshoot, `!= ALL` or `!= Any` return the correct values I need to insert from a select statement, but when I use NOT IN inside the statement it does not insert the correct values. If I comment out that line and execute the procedure it returns most of the correct values.

```
Not In ('KNOWN', 'NEW', 'UNKNOWN', 'SOLD') 
--Does not work
```

Comment: I've never seen the `!=ALL` syntax you're using.  What happens when you expand the `and` statement, i.e. `Status_G != 'KNOWN' AND Status_G != 'NEW'`, etc?  Are you doing a proper `END IF`? Does your `INSERT` statement work outside of the procedure?

Comment: What does that mean? Can you point me to documentation of it?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm

Comment: no the statement is within the procedure and yes the end if is correct

Comment: @Marc: The `!= ALL` (or maybe `<> ALL`) is standard SQL syntax since 1986.  That you've not seen shows that it is not often used, but it is valid.  However, `!= ALL` is equivalent to `NOT IN`.  `IN` is equivalent to `= ANY`.

Comment: Can you create a reproducable test case?

Comment: Does Status_G contain any NULL Value??

Comment: @Marc: Oracle's documentation, covering the rarely used ALL, ANY, and SOME: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions002.htm#sthref1919

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, thank you.  I managed to find it eventually, but your link is more "official" than what I found.  Nonetheless, I learned something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this...

```
And Status_G != ALL  ('KNOWN', 'NEW', 'UNKNOWN', 'SOLD')
```

...using the explicit approach first:

```
And 
(Status_G <> 'KNOWN' AND Status_G <> 'NEW' 
AND Status_G <> 'UNKNOWN' AND Status_G <> 'SOLD')
```

You can also do this:

```
And 
NOT (Status_G = 'KNOWN' OR Status_G = 'NEW' 
OR Status_G = 'UNKNOWN' OR Status_G = 'SOLD')
```

If that still(very explicit conditions) doesn't insert correct values, the error in your code is not on that line. Look on the other conditions of your IF statement, or perhaps your data

**OR PERHAPS**

The variable Status_G has a typo? please debug print the value of Status_G